# Grails Domain Object (GORM) inheritance

Tags: grails, grails-orm, domain-object

I have 4 Grails domain classes ( Domain1, Domain2, Domain3, Domain4). These domain objects map to **legacy tables** with exactly same set of columns. To be more precise, all of these tables have personFirstName, personLastName and personPhoneNumber columns.

The only thing different between these 4 domain classes is the table name they refer to.

Instead of copy/pasting same piece of code in four different places and just modifying this:

```
 static mapping = {

       table name:"legacy_table_name_A"     <====== (only difference)

       firstName column: "personFirstName"
       lastName column: "personLastName"
       phoneNumber column:"personPhoneNumber"
 }
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this all in one abstract class called **MyAbstractDomainClass** and have my Domain1, Domain2... extend it like this:

```
 class MyAbstractDomainClass {
        String firstName
        String lastName
        String phoneNumber

       static mapping = {
           firstName column: "personFirstName"
           lastName column: "personLastName"
           phoneNumber column:"personPhoneNumber"
      }
}

  class Domain1 extends MyAbstractDomainClass {

       static mapping = {

       }
  }
```

How do I implement the **static mapping** for each Domain classes to have a different table name?

I am using Grails 2.4.2